# Set variable in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rickshaw

I want to use the rickshaw module to create a graph in my app. I followed the instruction in here and didnt succedd : http://ngyewch.github.io/angular-rickshaw/#/home
this is my html :

```
<rickshaw
            rickshaw-options="options1"
            rickshaw-features="features"
            rickshaw-series="series1">
        </rickshaw>
```

this is my controller:

```
app.controller('GraphsController', function ($scope ) {
    $scope.options1 = {
        renderer: 'area'
    };
    $scope.series1 = [{
            name: 'Series 1',
            color: 'steelblue',
            data: [{x: 0, y: 23}, {x: 1, y: 15}, {x: 2, y: 79}, {x: 3, y: 31}, {x: 4, y: 60}]
        }, {
            name: 'Series 2',
            color: 'lightblue',
            data: [{x: 0, y: 30}, {x: 1, y: 20}, {x: 2, y: 64}, {x: 3, y: 50}, {x: 4, y: 15}]
        }];
});
```

anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might need to specify the controller on the `<rickshaw>` tag. Add this attribute tag like this:

```
<rickshaw ng-controller="GraphsController"
          rickshaw-options="options1"
          rickshaw-features="features1"
          rickshaw-series="series1">
</rickshaw>
```

Notice that I have now added the `ng-controller` attribute to the tags on `<rickshaw>` and specified the name of the controller you have defined in your JavaScript as its value. Hope this helps!

-- edit --

So, after a little investigation, there are a couple things that I would suggest. The first was already pointed out in another answer, make sure you are using `=` and not `==` in your attribute tags.

The second, make sure that you have used the correct variable names from your controllers scope object. I noticed that you are using `features`, but it doesn't look like it's being specified in the controller anywhere. Probably not causing any issues, but something to be aware of.

Finally, what I am guessing is the issue is that in your module specification, you are not including the `angular-rickshaw` module. Where you instantiate your angular app, you must include the angular-rickshaw module, like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myGraphApp', ['angular-rickshaw']);
```

Without this, the rickshaw module will not be included and nothing will work. Here is a working example in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cKumiX7kYc90gNA2jdZW?p=preview

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: I specified the controller in app.config. But I also tried your way and it didnt work.

Comment: is it possible that it doesnt work because the $scope doesnt know these variable. but how can I make rickshaw-options's value to be the read by $scope?

Comment: Thank you very much. The including of angular-rickshaw in the angular.module helped

Answer (score 0):

May be `rickshaw-options="options1"` instead of `rickshaw-options=="options1"`?